# select max (column) using linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

Can someone please help me in writing this query using linq:

```
select * from employee e
left outer join orders ord on e.employeeId = ord.employeeId
and ord.orderId = (select max(orderId) from Orders ord2 where ord.EmpIdentification = ord2.Empidentification)
Where e.employeeId = 1
```

Thank you

Comment: Which columns do you actually need? Both emp end order?

Comment: It would better that avoid doing such complex (nested) query using linq.  Linq may give you expected result, but may from a completely unexpected (sql) query

Comment: I need columns from both employee and orders

Comment: For the time being, Im just concerned about result.

Answer (score 0):

This should be equivalent but I am not sure what will happen if the join to orders doesn't find match and you are trying to test a null `ord.orderId`. I don't know what the SQL would do either.

```
var ans = from e in employee
          where e.employeeid == 1
          join ord in orders on e.employeeId equals ord.employeeId into ordj
          from ord in ordj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          where ord.orderId == (from ord2 in orders where ord2.empIdentification == ord.empIdentification select orderId).Max()
          select new { e, ord };
```